# How to load all the examples in to the @ExampleObject without specifying the ref so its visible in SwaggerUI?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus

I am developing a simple application where I would like to read the files from a remote URL and add them to the `@ExampleObject`. I am able to achieve this using CustomClass `SchemaFileReader implements OASFilter` but the only problem is that I need to manually specify the `name` of the file in the ref such as `@ExampleObject(name = "Example1", ref = "Example1.json")`.

Since I am reading the URL there can be many files and I do not know the name of all the files so I need an approach where I can add the `@ExampleObject` dynamically directly without specifying `ref`. Rather it should read all the data from the `examples`. Can someone please specify some logic on how to achieve this?

I have posted my complete code on GitHub: https://github.com/Aravinda93/code-with-quarkus.

As of now, I have added manually 2 files to my `@ExampleObject` by specifying the `ref` but I need a dynamic approach to add all the 3 files present in the `resourses/jsonfiles` without providing the `ref` for all the files individually.

To run the application, please follow the following steps:

1. Open the terminal for the project and run `mvn compile quarkus:dev`
2. Press `d` in the command line this should open the `Swagger-UI`.
3. Select `swagger-ui` from `SmallRye OpenAPI`
4. Expand `api/generate` and there we will see only 2 files under examples. I need an approach to get all 3 field without specifying the `ref` for all of them.

Comment: you cant modify the annotation data.  The annotation which has element `examples` will not allow you to plugin an array of examples.   It must be constants.  That means you need to do `@ExampleObject, @ExampleObject, @ExampleObject`.  You cant do `,examples = ExampleObject[]`

Comment: If you are looking for a completely dynamic approach, then you will need to define the paths dynamically, similar to how I showed you early.

Comment: @SMA Thanks a lot for your response. I totally agree `examples = ExampleObject[]` is not possible but is there a way we can create the customer annotation/class within which we will loop over the element in `examples` and create the `@ExampleObject` for each element in the `examples` then finally add that newly created annotation to my `RestResourceController`? or maybe inject the class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299717/how-to-create-an-instance-of-an-annotation

Comment: @SMA Thanks a lot for the response. I am looking into this answer. I will reach out to you if I need some guidance. Hope that's fine :)

Comment: @SMA I was able to make it work and seems like it's working fine for me. I have posted my answer for your reference :). Do let me know if there is any better way to achieve this. Also, I have one query as of now I am able to add both XML and JSON data but the problem is that while displaying in Swagger-UI the JSON part is displayed correctly but XML files are not displayed properly. It maybe because of `.getContent().getMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).addExample` but I am unable to pass multiple mediaType to it

Comment: Make your logic of generating examples smarter so you have 2 lists (jsons) and (xmls), then do `.getMediaType(json).addExample(jsonExamples) and .getMediaType(xml).addExample(xmlExamples)`

Comment: @SMA Thanks a lot for the response. Actuallly I tried that but I am getting some sort of error: `<!-- XML example cannot be generated; root element name is undefined -->` when I select `application/xml` in the SwaggerUI. When I searched about it found the answer that we need to add `wrapped:true` to XML media type. But not understanding exactly where to add in my code. Issue link: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4650#issuecomment-640815541

Answer (score 0):

After trying some things, finally, this worked for me. Posting here as it can be useful to someone in the future:

Following is my `RestControllerResponse`:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Content;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/api")
public class RestControllerResponse {

    @Path("/generate")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @RequestBody(description = "Testing Example without ref",
            content = @Content())
    public String generator(final Map<String, Object> input) throws Exception {
        return "Hello From Generator Method";
    }
}
```

Following is my `SchemaFileReader` which has the capability to read all files and respective subfolder with files and get the file contents and add to `examples`, pass the required URL to the `getFolderData` method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.OASFactory;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.OASFilter;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.Components;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.OpenAPI;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.examples.Example;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SchemaFileReader implements OASFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    @Override
    public void filterOpenAPI(OpenAPI openAPI) {

        Components defaultComponents = OASFactory.createComponents();
        if (openAPI.getComponents() == null) {
            openAPI.setComponents(defaultComponents);
        }

        try {
            //generateExamples().forEach(openAPI.getComponents()::addExample);
            generateExamples().entrySet().forEach(ex -> openAPI.getPaths().getPathItem("/api/generate").getPOST().getRequestBody().getContent().getMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).addExample(ex.getKey(), ex.getValue()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Map<String, Example> generateExamples() throws Exception {
        final Map<String, Example> examples = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        getFolderData(examples, "PLACE YOUR URL HERE");
        //getExamples(examples);
        return examples;
    }

    //If user has provided the folder then recursively loop over it to get the files and their contents
    private void getFolderData(final Map<String, Example> examples, final String inputURL) throws IOException {
        //Make the request to provided folder path and get the folder/files from it.
        final CloseableHttpResponse folderResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(inputURL));
        final String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(folderResponse.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        //If the folder API request provides valid response and contains the list of files or folders then loop over it else its plain/text with direct contents
        if (folderResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && ContentType.get(folderResponse.getEntity()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("application/json; charset=utf-8")) {

            final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);

            jsonArray.forEach(item -> {
                final JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) item;

                if (obj.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
                    //Make request to each file in the GitHub folder and obtain its contents
                    try {
                        final CloseableHttpResponse fileResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(obj.getString("download_url")));
                        //If the response code is 200 then add the contents to Example
                        if (fileResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                            final String fileResponseBody = EntityUtils.toString(fileResponse.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            if (obj.getString("download_url").contains(".json")) {
                                examples.put(obj.getString("name"), OASFactory.createExample().value(objectMapper.readValue(fileResponseBody, ObjectNode.class)));
                            } else if (obj.getString("download_url").contains(".xml")) {
                                examples.put(obj.getString("name"), OASFactory.createExample().value(fileResponseBody));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        getFolderData(examples, obj.getString("url"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } else if (folderResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && ContentType.get(folderResponse.getEntity()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain; charset=utf-8")) {
            //if direct file provided then add its content
            examples.put(inputURL.substring(inputURL.lastIndexOf("/")), OASFactory.createExample().value(objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, ObjectNode.class)));
        }
    }
}
```